# pass data from UIViesController to UIView, Swift ios

Tags: swift, xcode7

I'm trying to pass data from my UIViewcoontroller to a UIView that i assigned to a xib file on swift 2, i want that the var taxiName display on the label that is inside my UIView

```
    func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker!) -> UIView! {
    let infoWindow = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("infoWindow", owner: self, options: nil).first! as! InfoWindow
    if (marker.title == "Taxi0")
    {
        var taxiName = "Taxi0"

    return infoWindow
    }else if (marker.title == "Taxi1")
    {

    return infoWindow
    }else
    {
        return nil
    }

 }
```

This is my UIView

```
 Class InfoWindow: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var taxiName: UILabel!

var dataPassed: String!
@IBOutlet weak var nextView: UIButton!
```

}

Comment: Now you have local variable that do nothing. You may create set method at your InfoWindow and pass taxiName variable to it, then inside InfoWindow in setter make taxiName.text = value (input value in setter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) The easiest way in your case is:

```
infoWindow.taxiName.text = taxiName
```

2) You can create property or a function, that sets your variable:

```
Class InfoWindow: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var taxiName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var nextView: UIButton!
var dataPassed: String! {
    didSet {
        taxiName.text = dataPassed
    }
}
```

and then call

```
infoWindow.passedData = taxiName
```